# Store values in different variables in SQL, separated by (Comma) ","

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I need to separate values and store them in different variables in SQL,

for example

```
a='3100,3101,3102,....'
```

And the output should be

```
x=3100
y=3101
z=3102
.
.
.
```

Comment: after x,y,z what should come

Comment: i just need to store them individually and then using them extract their associated data from a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                         @delimiter varchar(5))
returns @split table (
  token varchar(200) not null )
as
  begin
      declare @list xml

      select @list = cast('<a>'
                          + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                          + '</a>' as xml)

      insert into @split
                  (token)
      select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
      from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

      return
  end

GO







declare @cad    varchar(100)='3100,3101,3102'
    select  *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by token ) as rn    from udf_splitstring(@cad,',')


token   rn
3100    1
3101    2
3102    3
```

Comment: what if there are more than 3 values to separate?

Comment: yes it will support  u can pass multiple values as input..@VaibhavSinha

Comment: One more query, Now I have two variables a='3101,3110' and b='3101-3110. How do I differentiate them using an if else condition or may be case condition? 3101 can be 311001(any length), it is dynamic! @chanukya

Comment: @VaibhavSinha b is having 3101 to 3110  or 3101-3110

Comment: having 3101 to 3110...its a range..but it would be entered like this only---'3101-3110'...i just need to differentiate what user has input..and then apply if else condition..@chanukya

Comment: this will not possible with '3101-3110' it will not generate between 3101 to 3110  but it will give (select * from udf_splitstring('3101-3110','-')
results 3101
3110

Comment: ;with cte(n)
  as
  (select 3101 as n
  union all
  select n+1 from cte
  where n<3110
  )
  select * from cte

Comment: this will generate numbers between two values

Comment: please accept my answer if satisifed your requirement..@VaibhavSinha

Answer (score 1):

The results of the Parse TVF can easily be incorporated into a JOIN, or an IN

```
Declare @a varchar(max)='3100,3101,3102'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@a,',')
```

Returns

```
RetSeq  RetVal
1       3100
2       3101
3       3102
```

The UDF if needed (much faster than recursive, loops, and xml)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Much faster than str-Parse, but limited to 8K
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use following query, it's much faster than other functions like cross apply and udf.

```
SELECT 
    Variables
    ,S_DATA
FROM    (
    SELECT
            Variables
            ,CASE   WHEN LEN(LIST2)>0 THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(LIST2, NUMBER+1, CHARINDEX(',', LIST2, NUMBER+1)-NUMBER - 1)))
                    ELSE NULL
            END AS S_DATA 
           ,NUMBER
    FROM(
        SELECT  Variables
                ,','+COMMA_SEPARETED_COLUMN+',' LIST2
                FROM Tb1
        )DT 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN TB N ON (N.NUMBER < LEN(DT.LIST2)) OR (N.NUMBER=1 AND DT.LIST2 IS NULL)
        WHERE SUBSTRING(LIST2, NUMBER, 1) = ',' OR LIST2 IS NULL
     ) DT2
     WHERE S_DATA<>''
```

and also you should create a table 'NUMBER' before running the above query.

```
CREATE TABLE TB (Number INT)
 DECLARE @I INT=0
 WHILE @I<1000
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TB VALUES (@I)
 SET @I=@I+1
 END
```